# Read server streaming data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, sails.js

This is my original question
[SailsJS stream status from backend to frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396292/sailsjs-stream-status-from-backend-to-frontend/28435378#28435378)

This question led me to this,
Now the server is streaming these information perfectly but I cannot get this streamed data from the server to be read by jQuery before the RESPOSE from the server is finished. ( In sailsJS it is res.end() )

So this is not the way i want it. I need jQuery to tell me 1/1000 is complted when the server send that information from the backend. and next tell me 2/1000 is completed.

Hope you understand what im asking of you.

Cheers.

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558129/process-a-continuous-stream-of-json

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740646/jquery-ajax-read-the-stream-incrementally